# trying to make a React todo list that displays JSON todo data and lets you add new todos but having both deletes all page content, how can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Each time a user tries to add a new todo its adding a blank li.

If i delete the  tag, and uncomment the map function in ToDoForm.jsx the user can add a new li that is not blank. I can't figure out how to make both work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/312tD.png

Here is the code:https://replit.com/@justinablair3/React-todo-app?v=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a type mismatch. When you add a new one you aren't adding a new object, you are adding a new string to the array. That is why the output is empty. Your TodoList component is looking for a title and completed but is not receiving those for the new items. Log out the todos and after you add a new one you will see that the array looks something like ['NewItem", {...}, {...}].

Change

```
setTodos([input, ...todos])
```

To something like:

```
setTodos([{title: input, id: Math.random(), completed: true}, ...todos])
```

So this way the child will know that this is an object and not a string.